# AutoFS/Automount doesnt mount ext4 imagefile on sshfs mount

Tags: linux, backup, sshfs, automount, autofs

I'm trying to automount an ext4 sparse imagefile on an sshfs mount but it doenst work like its supposed to be :/

I also mount the sshfs mount via autofs and this works like a charm but when I try to add the automount for the imagefile nothing happens...

The mountpoint /storagebox-mnt/storagebox-01 shows up but the /backup mountpoint for the imagefile doesn't so something has to be wrong in my config!

auto.master

```
/storagebox-mnt /etc/auto.sshfs uid=0,gid=0,--timeout=30,--ghost
/storagebox-nas-backupfs /etc/auto.img --timeout=30
```

auto.img

```
/backup -fstype=ext4,defaults,sync,dirsync,commit=1,loop :/storagebox-mnt/storagebox-01/backup.img
```

auto.sshfs

```
storagebox-01 -fstype=fuse,rw,nodev,nonempty,allow_other,reconnect,max_read=65536 :sshfs\#user@example.com\:/
```

If I run automount in the foreground no error message shows up...

edit#1: fixed the lookup errors by commenting out some includes in the default /etc/auto.master file but the result is the same! The sshfs mount works and the loop image mount doesn't.

sudo automount -f -v

```
Starting automounter version 5.1.1, master map /etc/auto.master
using kernel protocol version 5.02
lookup(dir): dir map /etc/auto.master.d missing or not readable
lookup(file): failed to read included master map dir:/etc/auto.master.d
lookup(file): failed to read included master map auto.master
mounted indirect on /storagebox-mnt with timeout 30, freq 8 seconds
ghosting enabled
mounted indirect on /storagebox-nas-backupfs with timeout 30, freq 8 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the `uid=0,gid=0` options in the auto.master file... The sshfs was mounted via the root account and the image file obviously wasn't... I changed the options to my useraccount for both mounts and now its working.